# Best way to implement an "endless page" in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pagination

Pagination sucks! The user should be able to scroll down forever, automatically pulling in new content when appropriate.

There's a [decent rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page) about this, but Ryan admits that his solution won't work in IE.

What's the best way to accomplish this in Rails (preferably in a jQuery-friendly fashion)?

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.dzone.com/

Comment: nice plugin, but seems like a neat way to DDOS your own server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried [jQuery.pageless](http://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless/tree/master) and it's working pretty well.

Comment: if you already use will_paginate – this is really easy to implement!

Answer (score 0):

This is the Rails plugin that works in the IE, Opera and FF:
http://bewhite.blogspot.com/2008/05/rails-endless-page-plugin.html

... and git repository:
git://github.com/shine/endless_page