# Pagination in Rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

I googled a bit but in vain. I want to know if there is any gem for pagination that uses scrollbar position to load more data. I meant to say that when scrollbar reaches bottom, I want to load more items list from ajax request and show them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a question on "[Endless Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809319/best-way-to-implement-an-endless-page-in-rails)" and the answer was to use jquery.pageless:
https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless

Heres a blog that implements this:
http://pedromtavares.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/endless-page-scrolling-with-rails-3-and-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a gem for the js part, but for the usual pagination you could check out [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) and create the js yourself.